# Feed validates but iTunes rejects due to parse error

Tags: php, xml, rss, itunes, podcast

I've validated my podcast feed with multiple feed validators and they all verify the XML is formatted correctly. However, when I validate the same feed through the iTunes Connect website, it fails validation due to a "parse error", with no indication of what's wrong.

Here's a link to the feed: https://weedporndaily.com/feed/podcast/

I based it off the JRE podcast feed(http://joeroganexp.joerogan.libsynpro.com/rss), so I'm not sure what's off with my formatting beyond some string sanitization issues.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by @Rogur_Wilmut1 on the Apple discussion boards here:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/32359603#32359603

The itunes "new-feed-url" tag was incorrectly pointing to the podcast homepage, rather than the actual feed URL.

https://weedporndaily.com/podcast/

Changed to this and works:
https://weedporndaily.com/feed/podcast/